# How to check if a range contains a word?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 Excel files that have in the column B the comments: `ok` or `check`. Column C contains the product numbers of the products that are either ok or need to be checked. I want to create a list (an overview) in another Excel file (4) of all the products that have the word "check" in column B in the other three Excel files (1,2,3).

I cannot use a pivot table in the three excels because it has to be refreshed manually. 
Filter is also not an option. I would like to use VBA/Macros in Excel.

Excel 1

```
Status  Product number          
check   1254968         
ok      5541485         
check   2153654         
ok      4588999         
ok      8954668         
ok      6945665         
check   7469968         
check   6665448
```

Excel 2

```
Status  Product number          
ok      7455561         
ok      5145684                 
ok      4589666                 
check   4896471                 
check   1117347                 
check   5656478                 
ok      5256488
```

Excel 3

```
Status  Product number          
ok      3389741         
check   6754889         
check   1489798         
ok      6489646
```

Excel 4

```
Products to check
1254968
2153654
7469968
6665448
4896471
1117347
5656478
6754889
1489798
```

I expect to have a list with all the product numbers that need to be checked in my 4th. Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new workbook in the same folder as the other files are located. Please consider to move away any other .xlsx files before running this macro :) If you need to run it in a specific folder and you are not able to move the files, please include a condition based on the name of the files that you do want to use. Otherwise, the below should be sufficient. Please read all comments in the code.

```
Sub test()

Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim HeadSet As Boolean

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

FolderName = "your/path/" 'full path name to folder where xlsx is located
file_name = Dir(FolderName & "*" & ".xlsx", vbDirectory) 'assuming the files are all  .xlsx

HeadSet = False 'for fun

'for each file in FolderName
Do While Right(file_name, 5) = ".xlsx" And file_name <> ""
    'open workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(file_name, False, True)
        With wb2.Sheets(1)
            For i = .Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row To .Range("B20000").End(xlUp).Row 'change .sheets(1) 1 = index to > your index, or "sheetname"
                If LCase(Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value)) = "check" Then 'checks lowercase, so condition should be lower
                    'create headers in output sheet
                    If HeadSet = False Then
                        wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Products"
                        wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Result of check"
                        HeadSet = True
                    End If
                    'change wb1.sheets(index) to your index, or the sheet name between ""
                    wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A" & wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                    wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B" & wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
                End If
            Next i 'next iteration
        End With
    wb2.Close False 'close workbook

    file_name = Dir 'go to next file
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your help. I tried it and it says that the variable FolderName is not defined. How should I define it? Dim FolderName As ...? And should I replace Sheets(1) with my sheet name from Excel 4 like this: Sheets(Table1)?

Comment: Please see my comment in the code...  in the code = FolderName = "your path/folder". Dim FolderName -> does not require a change. Your sheet name between quotes... please read the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did read all your comments and replace the path name. The Problem is that the Editor says I have to define the variable before using it, like you did with HeadSet -> you defined the variable as Boolean. FolderName is not defined. My question is: what should this be? A string? A Workbook? I didn't manage to clear this up. This is what I have in that row: FolderName = "H:/Desktop/Easy example Bilder" Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: If you need to declare it, you should: dim FolderName as string

Comment: So I had to declare all the variables in the Code before using them because I had the Option Explicit on :) The Code does unfortunately still not work.

Comment: Did you change the path to your folder? And are you working with .xlsx or .xls files? if .xls, change the 'do while condition'

Comment: Hello, yes I changed the path. I am working in a Network, could that be the Problem? I have only .xlsx and have put them all in the same Folder as the Excel file with the makro.

Comment: Hi, yes that is probably causing excel to not find the path. The way a path to a network location is build up, could be (i.e.) : \\ at the start, or \ instead of / and in some cases you need to replace the ' '(spaces) with '%20'.